# Calculating exponential Integrating

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to find the answer for below integration in Mathematica but I got no response. Could anyone help me?

```
Integrate[E^(a Cos[x - x0]), x]
```

Comment: It won't get you the result but `cos` should be `Cos` and you probably intend `e` to be `E`. All built-in symbols start with a capital letter. You will get a result for the definite integral `Integrate[E^(a Cos[x - x0]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because some simple integrals cannot be evaluated in terms of standard mathematical functions.

I would do the `Series` of `Cos[x]` first and then multiply all of the results from`Integrate`.

```
Times @@ Integrate[Exp[#] & /@ Table[x^n*SeriesCoefficient[Cos[x], {x, 0, n}], {n, 10}], x]
```

> [image]

Obtaining an approximate result with n=10.