# making colored contourplots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I plot a graph by the code I wrote. The graph shows zeros of 4 equations. I want to make the graph colored: regions which both datas2r and datas2r are negative becomes gray, regions which datas1i OR datas2i are not zero AND both datas2r and datas2r are negative become yellow and regions that one of the datas2r or datas2r are not negative becomes red.
Could anyone help? Any answers are highly appreciated.
This is my code.

```
datas1i = Flatten[Table[{v, e, s1i}, {v , 0, 40, 1}, {e, 2100, 27000, 50}], 1];
datas2r = Flatten[Table[{v, e, s2r}, {v , 0, 40, 1}, {e, 2100, 27000, 50}], 1];
datas1r = Flatten[Table[{v, e, s1r}, {v , 0, 40, 1}, {e, 2100, 27000, 50}], 1];
datas2i = Flatten[Table[{v, e, s2i}, {v , 0, 40, 1}, {e, 2100, 27000, 50}], 1]; 
p1 = ListContourPlot[datas1i, ContourShading -> False, Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Red]; p2 = ListContourPlot[datas2r, ContourShading -> False, Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Blue]; 
p3 = ListContourPlot[datas1r, ContourShading -> False, Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Green]; 
p4 = ListContourPlot[datas2i, ContourShading -> False, Contours ->{0}, ContourStyle -> Black]; 
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 30]]
```

Comment: I didn't underestand what do you mean? @Feyre

Comment: The term `Graph[]` is a built in function in *MMA*, and using that word to describe what you're doing with `ContourPlot[]` is misleading.
I retract my previous comment, as `datas1i` etc are quite long.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that they are too long and I don't know how to treat them. Any solutions? @Feyre

Comment: I don't think this can easily be done in the plots, have you tried just getting single datasets for each of the conditions?

Comment: What about the second part? Do you know how to stick two plots? @Feyre

Comment: I want to display them in a column. @Feyre

Comment: `GraphicsColumn` then :)

Comment: :)) second part solved! second part solved! tnx Feyre @Feyre

Comment: Your gray and yellow region conditions are not mutually exclusive, and thus the regions are not disjoint. If the yellow supersedes the gray, then generically what is painted gray won't be a (2D) region, but a set of points lying in the yellow (where both `data1i`, `data2i` are zero). If it is not a discrete set, but a line or a full-dimensional region, then I would need to see the data to understand. From a computational-graphics point of view, there is a big difference between sets of different dimensions.

Comment: You got answers for 13 out of 24 questions and you have accepted only one answer so far. Why is that? Are you not satisfied with the answers or there is something else going on?

Comment: Most of them are not complete answers and if I choose them, no one post a complete answer @MMM

Comment: Then you should comment on it showing your dissatisfaction and explain what exactly you want. The problem is that unanswered questions are pop up again n again. BTW, I am surprised that 12 answers are incomplete by your standard.

Comment: @saranj How is this not a complete answer? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130572/calculating-exponential-integrating

Comment: @saranj What's wrong with this answer? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135098/plotting-a-complicated-function

Comment: @saranj What about this one? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133665/plotting-a-continuous-function-in-discontinuously

Comment: @saranj I can go on and on...But you know what you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question then is to find, and plot a region subject to a certain condition of two data sets:

Suppose we have as datasets:

```
datas1r = 
  Flatten[Table[{i, j, Sin[i + j^2]}, {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}],
    1];
datas2r = 
  Flatten[Table[{i, j, Cos[i + j^2]}, {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}],
    1];
datas1i = 
  Flatten[Table[{i, j, Tan[i + j^2]}, {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}],
    1];
datas2i = 
  Flatten[Table[{i, j, Cosh[i + j^2]}, {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 
     0.1}], 1];
```

with:

```
p1 = ListContourPlot[datas1i, ContourShading -> False, 
   Contours -> {0}];
p2 = ListContourPlot[datas2r, ContourShading -> False, 
   Contours -> {0}];
p3 = ListContourPlot[datas1r, ContourShading -> False, 
   Contours -> {0}];
p4 = ListContourPlot[datas2i, ContourShading -> False, 
   Contours -> {0}];
```

Which are of the same form as the question.

We can find where these two are both not negative with `Select[]`
We can generate a region from these points, and plot it.

```
datag = Select[Transpose[{datas1r, datas2r}], 
   Last@#[[1]] < 0 && Last@#[[2]] < 0 &];
regiong = datag[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]];
grey = RegionPlot[DelaunayMesh@regiong, 
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
   BoundaryStyle -> RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.4]];
datar = Select[Transpose[{datas1r, datas2r}], 
   Last@#[[1]] > 0 || Last@#[[2]] > 0 &];
regionr = datar[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]];
red = RegionPlot[DelaunayMesh@regionr, 
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.8, 0.4, 0.4], 
   BoundaryStyle -> RGBColor[0.5, 0.2, 0.2]];
datay = Select[
   Transpose[{datas1i, datas2i, datas1r, 
     datas2r}], (Last@#[[1]] != 0 || 
       Last@#[[2]] != 0) && (Last@#[[3]] < 0 && 
       Last@#[[4]] < 0) &];
regiony = datay[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]];
yellow = RegionPlot[DelaunayMesh@regiony, 
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.6, 0.6, 0.2], 
   BoundaryStyle -> RGBColor[0.4, 0.5, 0.2]];
```

Which can then be added to the show:

```
Show[red, yellow, grey, p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

[image]

Comment: But what about the condition on datas1i and datas2i? could it be added to the show in the same way?

Comment: @saranj Yes, but you need to change the `Select[]` criteria. to `datai = Select[Transpose[{datas1r, datas2r}], 
   Last@#[[1]] != 0 && Last@#[[2]] != 0 &];`

Comment: I think your comment is not correct. Because I want  "regions which datas1i OR datas2i are not zero AND both datas2r and datas2r are negative become yellow"

Comment: `Select[Transpose[{datas1i,dats2i, datas1r, datas2r}], (Last@#[[1]] != 0 || Last@#[[2]] != 0) && (Last@#[[3]] >= 0 && Last@#[[4]] >= 0) &];`

Comment: and how does region (in your code) change?

Comment: @saranj I've added info for all three situations in my example in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry Fery but it still doesn't work properly :(. I changed bigger or equal in datay = Select[
   Transpose[{datas1i, datas2i, datas1r, 
     datas2r}], (Last@#[[1]] != 0 || 
       Last@#[[2]] != 0) && (Last@#[[3]] >= 0 && 
       Last@#[[4]] >= 0) &]; to smaller or equal but it didn't show the region in yellow color

Comment: Maybe you should change regiony = datay[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]]; to something else?

Comment: I found the problem! I should call yellow after grey in show function

Comment: Shouldn't the gray and yellow regions be identical using this data, at least the way I interpret "`data2i` [is] not zero" (`Cosh[i + j^2] != 0`)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 You're right, I made an error in the definition of the grey area. Fixed the code, but kept the original image for now.

Comment: Frey, Is there any way to substitute some stars instead of red color?

Comment: @saranj You can add `, PlotStyle -> 
 Texture["some image"]` to `RegionPlot[]` You need to find a good image for that though.

Comment: Just one more question Frey: How can I put label for regions with different colors?

Comment: @saranj You could make a custom legend table with `LineLegend` and show it next to your plot as in `GraphicsRow[{Show[...],LineLegend[...]}]`